# Java, image is changing to wrong rgb values

Tags: java, colors, rgb, bufferedimage, javax.imageio

i wrote a java code to change all the red values of a black and white image to 255, so the output would be a red image.
But its not red, instead it outputs a brighter image.
What did I do wrong?

```
 File bwgFile = new File("X:/Java/Documents/NetBeansProjects/colour/input/bwg.png");
BufferedImage bwgImage = ImageIO.read(bwgFile);
int width=bwgImage.getWidth();
int height=bwgImage.getHeight();
for(int w=0; w<width; w++){
  for(int h=0; h<height; h++){
      int pixel = bwgImage.getRGB(w,h);
      Color bwg = new Color(pixel);
      int c=bwg.getRed();
      Color red = new Color(255,c,c);
      int cpixel = red.getRGB();
      bwgImage.setRGB(w,h,cpixel);
  }
}
    ImageIO.write(bwgImage, "png", new File("X:/Java/Documents/NetBeansProjects/colour/output/c.png"));
```

[input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l96g7.png)
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IU67J.png)

EDIT:
I have found out what the problem was, apparently when the input is a greyscale image it will try to make the output a greyscale image as well thus making it darker when blue and green colors get removed and brighter when red gets added. not using a grayscale image as input fixed it.

Comment: Cause color channels indicate brightness of a color? You still have your Green and Blue channel. If you all set them to 255, you get white.

Comment: i dont set them all to 255, only red.

Comment: If u look at the output image you can see that the image isn't white. (I've included links to the images in case you hadn't noticed.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you're trying to do, you're trying to create a greyscale image, except that it is "redscale", using only shades of red. Therefore, you need to compute the greyscale constant of each pixel.

From wikipedia ([Greyscale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grayscale)), the luminance of a pixel Y = 0.2126R + 0.7152G + 0.0722B. So, try this

```
int pixel = bwgImage.getRGB(w,h);
Color bwg = new Color(pixel);
float c = (0.2126f * bwg.getRed() + 0.7152f * bwg.getGreen() + 0.0722f * bwg.getBlue());
int cc = (int)Math.round(c);
Color red = new Color(cc, 0, 0);
int cpixel = red.getRGB();
bwgImage.setRGB(w,h,cpixel);
```

Alternatively, you can simply retain the red component and set green and blue to 0. This will leave you with just the "redness" of each pixel.

```
int pixel = bwgImage.getRGB(w,h);
Color bwg = new Color(pixel);
int c=bwg.getRed();
Color red = new Color(c,0,0);
int cpixel = red.getRGB();
bwgImage.setRGB(w,h,cpixel);
```

**NOTE:** This solution above only works on images that are not using `IndexColorModel`. You can check the color model using BufferedImage's `getColorModel()`. For `IndexColorModel`, `setRGB()` does not work directly and instead picks a color in the index closest to the set color, as per HaraldK's comment. To achieve the desired result for images using `IndexColorModel`, you can create a new BufferedImage with TYPE_INT_ARGB:

```
BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
```

Then, write the calculated pixel colors to this new image and save the new image instead.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Color parameter outside of expected range: Red
 at java.awt.Color.testColorValueRange(Color.java:310)
 at java.awt.Color.<init>(Color.java:395)
 at java.awt.Color.<init>(Color.java:369)
 at colour.Colour.main(Colour.java:50)
C:\Users\Emma\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.1\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)

Comment: @ergoforce, sorry, removed the * 255 on the 3rd line. The original values are already between 0 and 255.

Comment: I also tried your second suggestion but I still end up with a greyscale image, notably darker than the input even though the Blue and Green values should be 0 for each pixel.

Comment: Same result with the improved first answer, im getting a darker greyscale image

Comment: I have found out what the problem was although I dont understand why it was a problem, apparently when the input is a greyscale image it will try to make the output a greyscale image as well thus making it darker when blue and green colors get removed and brighter when red gets added. not using a grayscale image as input fixed it. Thanks for your improved code you helped alot!

Comment: @ergoforce I believe it depends on the format of the input image. Try checking the value of bwgImage.getType() and see whether it corresponds to BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB

Comment: The current accepted answer is incorrect. While you deserve the rep for helping the OP solve his problem, you should at least update the answer to help future readers. :-) The problem is that the `setRGB(...)` methods of `BufferedImage` don't work as intended for grayscale or indexed color models (instead of setting the exact color, it will choose the "nearest" available in the color model).

Comment: @haraldK Thanks! Have updated my answer to add a footnote.